# Why is the result of `cl_gui_textedit->get_textstream` empty?

Tags: abap

I'm using the ABAP standard class `cl_gui_textedit` to read text from a textarea on my selection screen. But the result after calling the method `get_textstream` on the instance is empty.

Minimal working example:

```
REPORT z_mwe_textarea_bug.

DATA lr_edit TYPE REF TO cl_gui_textedit.
DATA lr_docker TYPE REF TO cl_gui_docking_container.

PARAMETERS p_dummy TYPE string DEFAULT 'just for testing'. ""// <--- need this to show selection screen.

INITIALIZATION.
  CREATE OBJECT lr_docker
    EXPORTING
      ratio = 60.
  CREATE OBJECT lr_edit
    EXPORTING
      parent = lr_docker.

  lr_docker->dock_at( EXPORTING side = cl_gui_docking_container=>dock_at_left ).

START-OF-SELECTION.

  DATA lv_text_from_textarea TYPE string.
  lr_edit->get_textstream( IMPORTING text = lv_text_from_textarea ).   ""// <-- why is lv_text_from_textarea empty??
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You (or I, answering my own question) have to call `cl_gui_cfw=>flush( )` afterwards. Like this:

```
lr_edit->get_textstream( IMPORTING text = lv_text_from_textarea ). ""// <-- lv_text_from_textarea still empty
cl_gui_cfw=>flush( ). ""//<-- now it's not empty anymore.
```

**Disclaimer:** *Found the answer on [abapforum.de](https://www.abapforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21097) but removed all the useless (and german) discussions and added a minimal working example to my question.*